# How to skip the mark on the first data point while still including it in the line graph in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to create a graph that plots the points and joins them with a line. But while plotting, I wanted the line to start from zero, so I added (0,0) to my data points file. But it also places a mark at that point. I only want the line to start from (0,0) but not a mark at that point. I did it with a workaround by plotting two plots. One with just marks and using the [skip first] option and the other with just the line. But is there a better way to do this with just one plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `mark phase=2`.

In the code below  I used `\addplot +[mark phase=2] ..`, where the `+` indicates that the option is appended to the default settings. Whether you need that `+` yourself depends on how you've set up your plot.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[mark phase=2] coordinates {(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```